# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer fails when there IDM

Tags: angular, spring, pdf-viewer, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

*How to view pdf directly in ngx-extended-pdf-viewer when a client has IDM installed? I am using Angular 10 and spring boot rest api to download the file?*

Comment: Please give us some context. What is IDM?

Comment: I am sorry, Internet Download Manager is grabbing the file before it is loaded by ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code as this and it works perfectly the pdf file is not grabed by the Internet Download Manager.

```
@RequestMapping("/downloadFile")
    public FileSystemResource download(@RequestParam Long documentId, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        Resource resource = storageService.loadAsResource(documentId);
        return new FileSystemResource(resource.getFile());
    }
```